# Setting color on label gridline Highcharts

Tags: highcharts

Is there a way to change the color of a line on my label? 
[image]

Here is my code:

```
  xAxis: {
    categories: ['Jan', 'Feb', 'Mar', 'Apr', 'May', 'Jun', 'Jul', 'Aug', 'Sep', 'Oct', 'Nov', 'Dec'],
    lineColor: '#FF0000',
    labels:{
        lineColor: '#FF0000',
    },
    gridLineColor: 'red',
  },

  yAxis: {
    lineColor: '#FF0000',
    lineWidth: 1,
    labels:{
    x: -50,
    }
  },
```

For reference: http://jsfiddle.net/vq1tqhrs/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to set [`tickColor`](https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/xAxis.tickColor), like this:

```
xAxis: {
  tickColor: 'red'
  ...
}
```

**Working example:** http://jsfiddle.net/ewolden/vq1tqhrs/1/